# Nginx Query String rewrite

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a configuration as below, but I am getting 500 error. Where could this error be?

```
upstream masterservers {server 192.168.1.1:8000;}
upstream slaveservers {server 192.168.1.2:8001;}

map $request_uri $redirect_to {
    "target=master"     masterservers;
    "target=slave"   slaveservers;
}

server {
    listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.1.10;

       location / {
        proxy_pass              http://$redirect_to;
    }

}
```

When I call the URL as below, I get the following error.

http://192.168.1.10/app/index.html?target=master

http://192.168.1.10/app/index.html?target=slave

Nginx Log: `*2 invalid URL prefix in "http://", client: 192.168.1.11, server: 192.168.1.10, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.10", referrer: "http://192.168.1.10/app/index.html?target=master"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing your `$request_uri`, which is equals to `/app/index.html?target=master` from your example, to `target=master` and `target=slave` strings. None matched, so `$redirect_to` variable becomes an empty string. If you want to check if the `$request_uri` contains a `target=master` or `target=slave` substrings, you can use regex patterns inside the `map` block:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_to {
    "~target=master"     masterservers;
    "~target=slave"      slaveservers;
}
```

or better check the `$arg_target` variable value:

```
map $arg_target $redirect_to {
    master     masterservers;
    slave      slaveservers;
}
```

Also consider using some `default` value when no `target` query argument is specified in request (or its value is invalid):

```
map $arg_target $redirect_to {
    master     masterservers;
    slave      slaveservers;
    default    masterservers;
}
```

The last one can be simplified to

```
map $arg_target $redirect_to {
    slave      slaveservers;
    default    masterservers;
}
```

Or make some preliminary check like

```
map $arg_target $redirect_to {
    master     masterservers;
    slave      slaveservers;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.10;

    if ($redirect_to = '') {
        return 501; # HTTP 501 Not Implemented
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$redirect_to;
    }

}
```

**Update**

If I understand your additional question correctly - how to load all the assets from the same upstream as the main HTML file - you can try to get an upstream name from the HTTP `Referer` header value if the `target` query argument is absent using two chained `map` blocks (here are regex really come in place):

```
map $arg_target $redirect_to {
    master     masterservers;
    slave      slaveservers;
    default    $by_referer;
}
map $http_referer $by_referer {
    "~target=master"     masterservers;
    "~target=slave"      slaveservers;
}
server {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. How can I get rid of 500 error for css and js files?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, if I am, check the update to an answer.